# when I use foreach in laravel's blade, last() or end() not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

`end()` or `last()` are not working...What to do?

```
@foreach($students as $student)

@foreach($payment_heads as $payment_head)

      <td>

      @foreach ($student->payment_detail as $payment_detail_one)


           @if($payment_detail_one->payment_head_id==$payment_head->id)
              <?php

                $total=$total+$payment_detail_one->amount;

              ?>

              @if($payment_detail_one === end($$student->payment_detail)) 
             {{$payment_detail_one->amount}}
             @endif

          @endif

      @endforeach
  </td>
  @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

Comment: `end($$student->payment_detail)` used double `$$`

Comment: also see docs [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#the-loop-variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#the-loop-variable)

Answer (score 0):

See docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#the-loop-variable.
Wrong is `end($$student->payment_detail)` used double `$$`
You can use this

```
@foreach($students as $student)
    @foreach($payment_heads as $payment_head)
        <td>
            @foreach ($student->payment_detail as $payment_detail_one)
                @if($payment_detail_one->payment_head_id==$payment_head->id)

                    <?php
                        $total = $total + $payment_detail_one->amount;
                    ?>

                    @if ($loop->last)
                        {{$payment_detail_one->amount}}
                    @endif

                @endif
            @endforeach
        </td>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: sorry, wrongly i got $$, but in orginally i got single $. but till get blank result.